# I am trying to use processing in Eclipse, but I'm fairly confused--where do I import processing? Assume I know nothing

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

[image]

This is the error I'm getting. Am I supposed to download another library? Surely creating a PApplet isn't how this goes?

> Error: Could not find or load main class
> finishedBlossomingTree.BlossomingTreeKinectRenderDemo Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: processing/core/PApplet

Comment: *Am I supposed to download another library?* - have you added the library to your classpath? try clicking on "fix project setup"  Is there a reason not to use the the Processing IDE?

Comment: the three `.jar` files from `core/library/` folder of processing (standard installation) must be included into the CLASSPATH of that project

Comment: check the question: [Use processing in Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21309851/85421)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being that I need the 64 bit version of jogl and I can't create a custom user library, like I had--I had to add it to build path as a part of referenced libraries

Comment: to be able to `import processing.core.PApplet` ??

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, because it's not solving the same issue in another project @user85421